# Facebook post functionaly in my Phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova

I wanna to add in my Phonegap app a facebook button so that when I click on it the ad of my app will be sent to the friends of the user. 
What is the best way to achieve this.. Is there out there a good working plugin some code examples to whom I can refer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin @ [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)